# How can I validate to check if a record having this value exists in a table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am working on a Laravel project and I have the following problem related to validation.

In the past I created this validation rules (related to a new user registration form):

```php
$rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'surname' => 'required',
    'login' => 'required|unique:pm_user,login',
    'email' => 'required|email|confirmed|unique:pm_user,email',
    'pass' => 'required|required|min:6',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
];
```

In particular this rules array contains this rule:

```
'login' => 'required|unique:pm_user,login',
```

it seems to me that this last rule check if the inserted login doesn't yet exist into the **pm_user** table (so it ensure that not exist a row of the **pm_user** table having the same inserted value into the **login** column).

Is it? Correct me if I am doing wrong assertion.

If it work in this way now my problem is how to do the opposite thing in another set of validation rule.

In particular I have this other array of rule (defined into a class extending`FormRequest`:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'token' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

In particular I have to ensure that into the **pm_user** table yet exist a record having the value of the column named **email** that is the same of the **emai** field of the request.

How can I change this request to perform this validation rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 already has a built in validation rule for this called `exists`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists

I think you are looking for:

```
'email' => 'required|email|exists:pm_user,email'
```